Two PDFs (or CDFs) the same if "x" values different
I've been given two sets of data and I need to figure out if they're the "same". Each data set consists of a PDF and a CDF (but not the underlying samples). The PDF and CDF data is in the form of x, y values and they're digitized samples of continuous data. I don't know what the underlying distribution is (I don't know if the underlying distribution is beta, or log-normal etc.)
I have data that looks something like:
Set1:

x1: [1023, 1024, 1025, ...]
CDF1: [0, 0.001, 0.0025, ....]
PDF1: [0, 0.001, 0.0015, ...]
Length1: n1

Set2:

x2: [1021.5, 1026.5, 1031.5, ...]
CDF2: [0, 0.002, 0.0043, ....]
PDF2: [0, 0.002, 0.0023 ...]
Length2: n2

Importantly:

n1 != n2 - the lengths are not the same, meaning the data sets don't "line up".
Sometimes, x1[0] != x2[0] - the first x values will mostly be the same, but sometimes they'll be slightly different
Sometimes, x1[-1] != x2[-1] - the final x values will mostly be the same, but sometimes they'll be slightly different

Obviously, I thought of a Kolmogorov–Smirnov test, but my reading suggests the test depends on the CDF values 'lining up' on the x axis, which is not my case here. I thought of interpolating my data sets to the same x-axis, but I'm concerned that will introduce fitting errors.
I looked at other non-parametric tests, but it seems to be the same problem everywhere because the x-values don't align.
Are there non-parametric tests that don't rely on CDF/PDF data sampled at the same interval?

You can probably adapt a KS test to your use case, but you should consider how meaningful the result is. Like all significance tests, the KS test has the feature/bug that any microscopic difference becomes "significant" with a large enough sample. My advice is to work out some metric for substantial or practical difference between the distributions, i.e. to think about what difference it makes to you or to anybody when the distributions are not the same; this is the so-called "effect size" approach. A web search will find some resources about that.

@RobertDodier Can you expand your comment as an answer so I can accept your answer? Your approach was much more helpful than KS etc. BTW - I ended up doing something quite different and more meaningful to my users.

Thanks, but I don't think it really merits being an answer, better suited as just a comment. But I'm curious, what did you come up with for your problem?

@RobertDodier I ended up creating a polygon representing the difference in area for the two distributions. If the distributions are the same, the area of the polygon is zero. If they're different, the area is not zero. In reality, having different sampling intervals will always make the results slightly different, so my test was if the difference was less than some small threshold (under 1%). This isn't enough of a test by itself, but it does get me a good part of the way.

Not a programming question, hence off-topic here. Please see https://stackoverflow.com/tags/statistics/info

I followed the hints from Robert Dodier and did not use KS. I used a polygon representation of both data sets and calculated the area difference. If the difference was greater than a threshold, the test failed.
The K-S test was the wrong approach here. Interpolating the results to the same "grid" introduced numerical artifacts that confused the results. Morale of the story: tests have limits.

Use the two sample Kolmogorov-Smirnov test and interpolate for the misaligned values of x. Per Wikipedia, the number of samples can differ, and the interpolation should just hold the left value for the CDF, as it is the number of samples less than the value x over the number of samples (this is specified in the one-sample Kolmogorov-Smirnov statistic section in the article)
